# A form on Chrome work only when I add the value="" attribute in the input

Tags: php, html, forms, google-chrome

I have an issue and I can't find any solution since 3 hours now,

I have a simple html login form that leads to a php script that checks if the account exists.

Everything works perfectly when on my "Username" and "Password" fields I indicate data in the "value" attribute, but when I type the username and password myself, the page loads to the infinite and I don't understand why at all.

Btw, it seems that it work fine with Edge.

```
<form class="mb-0" action="http://www.localhost:80/cms/controller/loginController.php" method="POST">

<label for="login-form-username">Nom d'utilisateur</label>
<input type="text" id="login-form-username" name="username" required="required"  class="form-control">

<label for="login-form-password">Mot de passe</label>
<input type="password" id="login-form-password" name="password" required="required"  class="form-control">

<input type="submit" class="button button-3d button-black m-0" id="login-form-submit" name="login" value="Connexion">
<a href="#" class="float-right">Mot de passe oublié</a></form>
```

If I add value="admin" for username and value="1234" for password and I submit the form, it works fine.

My loginController.php script:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

        $username = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['username']));
        $password = saltAndCrypt($_POST['password']);

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserName = :UserName AND UserPassword = :UserPassword');
        $stmt->execute(array(':UserName' => $username, ':UserPassword' => $password));

        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $userInfos = $stmt->fetch();
            $user = new User();
            $user->login($userInfos['UserID']);
            exit;
        } else {
            $flash->addFlashMessage('Mot de passe incorrect', "danger");
            $_SESSION['captchaLogin'] = time() + 30;
        }

    }
}
```

And the function $user->login should connect the user and redirect him on the dashboard. The function works fine cause when I try it manually, it works fine.

```
    public function login($user_id, $params = null){
    global $pdo;
    global $flash;

    if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
        unset($_SESSION['user']);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserID = :UserID');
    $stmt->execute(array(':UserID' => $user_id));
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    $UserID = $row['UserID'];

    $_SESSION['user']['pseudo'] = $row['UserName'];
    $_SESSION['user']['auth'] = $UserID;
    $_SESSION['user']['rang'] = $row['UserLevel'];

    header("Location: ".PATH_SOURCE_ESPACE_CLIENT.LIEN_HOME_CONNECTED);
    return true;    
}
```

Can somebody see what is the issue here?

Comment: What do you mean by "*the page loads to the infinite*" ?

Comment: Side note: You should look into using `password_hash` and `password_verify` for password management in login scripts.

Comment: _Small Point_  `isset()` can test multiple variables and it tests them using an AND condition, so `if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {` is a little more concise

Comment: PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: It is normal to SELECT using only the username and then test that the HASHED password matches the entered password. This works great using `password_verify()`

Comment: `saltAndCrypt()` is not vanilla PHP and is not shown here, so that might well be your issue

Comment: saltAndCrypt is a simple function I made and which work fine,
Thanks for your advices about the isset and password_verify I didn't know, but that not resolve my issue, I tested everything to debug and nothing work or show error...

Comment: Pleasae show us `saltAndCrypt()` the fact that it does not produce errors does not mean it is doing the right things

Comment: Also a little odd that your main code `select * from users` and then you do it all again in the `login` method

Comment: I do it again cause I have a oauth login method where I need to connect only by passing the user ID, so the issue here is whith the classic login form, so no issue for me here.

@RiggsFolly I deleted the function and it doesn't work, I try to delete the more things on my code but I have the issue with chrome

Comment: I made a new test, on loginController I put "$username = $password = "test"; (I deleted the crypt/hash function for my test, and the log of the account is test:test), it works fine, but when I put: "$password = $_POST['password '] and $username = $_POST['username'] it don't work event when I write test and test !

Comment: After more tests, it seems the reason is the name of my input, when the field name is "username" or "login-username" it doesn't work, and when it's "test555" it's work fine, how this is possible?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/3Wtdtc9.png When the fields are fill in html with 'value=""', it work fine when I submit the form, but when there is no value="" attribute and i write test & test, it doesn't work, please help